# css resize function and cursor position when resize

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I created a little script for showing a modal window, and letting me resize and move this window.

**The script can be tested here:** https://jsfiddle.net/5ysja6tn/4/

The first problem I have is that when I try to resize the window, the cursor doesn't follow the corner and separate too. My question is about how I can make the cursor stay in the corner while resizing the window.

Another thing is I think I use the CSS flex property badly, because the container inside in orange color doesn't change height when resizing the window, and I tried different things but I can't get this container to get the necessary height when resized.

And the last question is about if it's a good idea to use the CSS resize property or not. I use it because I have many problems using jquery UI, and I don't know if there is an easy way to use jquery for resizing. I don't want to use plugins really, because in the end it will create problems with my other scripts.

Here is my code:

```js
"use strict"

function move(idd) {
  $('' + idd + '').on({
    mousedown: function(e) {
      $(window).data({
        down: true,
        oX: e.offsetX,
        oY: e.offsetY,
        el: this
      })
    },
    mouseup: function(e) {
      $(window).data('down', false)
    },
  })
  $(window).on({
    mousemove: function(e) {
      var data = $(window).data()
      if (data.down) {
        $(data.el).css({
          left: e.clientX - data.oX,
          top: e.clientY - data.oY
        });
      }
    },
  })
}

function res(idd) {
  jQuery("" + idd).css("resize", "both");
  jQuery("" + idd).css("overflow", "hidden");
}
```

```css
#dragg {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dragg">
  <div id="header_win" onmouseover="move('#dragg');" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:35px;background-color:grey;">Mover</div>
  <div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:300px;margin:auto;background-color:orange;display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
    Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>
  </div>
  <div id="footer_win" onmouseover="res('#dragg');" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:20px;bottom:0px;background-color:green;">Resize</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use Draggable? You posted this with the `jquery-ui` tag, are you not using jQuery UI?